Namespace files and filenames are not replaced with the namespace’s prefix using Cumulusci deploy command
I am trying to do Namespace Injectionion Cumulusci deploy command
Getting below error
Error: Could not process MDAPI response: Update of CustomField Financial__c.Budget__c: Error on line 1016, col 13: referenceTo value of 
'Budget__c' does not resolve to a valid sObject type

Files and filenames are not replaced with the namespace’s prefix
I am running below command
cci task run deploy --path .\force-app\main\default 

Cumuculci.yml
project:
    name: Project
    package:
        name: Amp_Impact
        namespace: XXX
        api_version: '58.0'
    source_format: sfdx

    dependencies:
        - subfolder: force-app/main/default
          namespace_inject: XXX
          unmanaged: True

tasks:
    robot:
        options:
            suites: robot/Project/tests
            options:
                outputdir: robot/XXX/results

    robot_testdoc:
        options:
            path: robot/XXX/tests
            output: robot/XXX/doc/Project_tests.html
            
    run_tests:
        options:
            managed: true
            namespace: XXX

    deploy:
        description: Deploy metadata with namespace injection
        class_path: cumulusci.tasks.salesforce.Deploy
        options:
            path: src
            inject_namespace: True        

orgs:
    scratch:
        dev:
            config_file: orgs/dev.json
            days: 30
        qa:
            config_file: orgs/dev.json
            days: 30
        feature:
            config_file: orgs/feature.json
        beta:
            config_file: orgs/beta.json
        release:
            config_file: orgs/release.json

